# Hide all AutoFilter dropdown with one line of code

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a rather big Excel file with a lot of data. I use a validation list which results in a filter through VBA. Because I have 52 columns (one for every week of the year) I automatically get a small dropdown arrow in every header.

I use this little piece of code to hide the dropdown arrow manually for each column:

```
Worksheets("Agenda").Range("B6").AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
```

This works perfectly, however when I create a for loop with it to loop through all 52 columns it takes a lot of time for the code to be completed, and it runs every time someone adds a filter with the validation list.

Is there any way to do this by just using one line of code? Can I set VisibleDropDown to False for all the columns in said table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create your table as a range, and then change the *.Range() to reflect the name of the Range.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for the for loop?

Comment: @Sam I created the range, but when I run the macro I get error 1004 method AutoFilter from class Range was not succeeded (had to translate this from Dutch to English). Do you call the range exactly the same, so like *.Range("nameofrange")?

Comment: @FrK - I got part of it wrong...see my answer below...basically, once you name the Range, then you do `*.ListObjects()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is pretty straight forward I think...
 - Select all your data
 - Select "Format As Table"
 - Go to Table Ribbon
 - Rename Table to "myBigTable"
 - Macro line: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("YourTableName").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False`

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly! I was only focussing on VisibleDropDown... I had no idea there was a ShowAutoFilterDropDown property for ListObjects.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work for me. However, `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTableName").ShowAutoFilter = False` seemed to do the trick for me.