# Can I remove ALL autofilter dropdown buttons from the entire worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Edit: Thanks for the help; I ended up going a totally different route with this problem. After my autofilter runs, I have a separate sub to delete all the filtered out data, so then I can just turn the autofilter *off* and obviously there's no more dropdown arrows because it isn't running. Sometimes simple really is better : )

Hopefully this is an easy one that someone can help with- I know there should be an easy way to do this, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I have my autofilter successfully running and everything is working nicely, but I hate the look of the autofilter dropdown arrows in my header cells. Is there a way I can remove the dropdowns from the entire worksheet?

Right now I'm just doing it piecemeal, which works, but seems unnecessarily long. Current code is as follows:

```
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:=Array("FSA Healthcare 01/01/2022 with Carryover", "Dependent Care 01/01/2022", "FSA Limited 01/01/2022 with Carryover"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:="CBNU", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="CBU"
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:="Active"
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=9, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:=">0"
    'Filters by plan type, status, division
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Admin Notes"
    Range("J2").Font.Bold = True
    Range("J2").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Range("J2").BorderAround , LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    'Adds "Admin Notes" text
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=8, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=10, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=11, VisibleDropDown:=False
    Range("A2:L1000").AutoFilter Field:=12, VisibleDropDown:=False
    'Removes filter dropdown button
```

It seems like this is not very efficient since I have to basically repeat this block of code for multiple sheets and at least 8 lines are doing the same thing, but I'm not sure how to improve it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro) work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the dropdown arrows at all or can you set up the filters without them? Link attached gives a good example of how to set up filters without arrows.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4834-excel-hide-filter-arrows.html

Here is the VBA code for the advanced filter option.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'

    Range("A1:AP8").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("L1:L8"), Unique:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$M$8").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="enter criteria here"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use tables/listobjects - there you have `ShowAutoFilterDropdown`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535009/16578424.

If you have a normal range it is a bit more complex.

First of all: yes, you have to set `visibledropdown` per each column.
And yes, you have to do it for all columns individually. Another challenge: You want to keep the criterias, if a filter was chosen.

But you can build a generic sub that takes a range and handles the filter settings.

```vb
Public Sub hideRangeFilterArrows(rg As Range)

If Not rg.ListObject Is Nothing Then
    hideListObjectFilterArrows rg.ListObject
Else
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Parent
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim af As AutoFilter, f As Filter
    Set af = ws.AutoFilter

    Dim i As Long, c As Range
    For Each c In rg.Rows(1).Cells
        i = i + 1
        Set f = af.Filters(i)
        If f.On = True Then  'we want to keep the criteria
            If f.Operator = 0 Then   'simple filter
                c.AutoFilter field:=i, Criteria1:=f.Criteria1, visibledropdown:=False
            ElseIf f.Operator <> xlFilterDynamic And f.Operator <> xlFilterValues Then
                'those two filters are too complex to handle here
                c.AutoFilter field:=i, Criteria1:=f.Criteria1, Operator:=f.Operator, Criteria2:=f.Criteria2, visibledropdown:=False
            End If
        Else    'easy - there is no filter on this column
            c.AutoFilter field:=i, visibledropdown:=False
        End If
    Next

End If
End Sub

Public Sub hideListObjectFilterArrows(lo As ListObject)
If Not lo.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
    lo.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
End If
End Sub
```

You can then call this generic sub for your specific range, e.g. like this

`hideListObjectFilterArrows ActiveSheet.Range("A2:L1000")`